# Compress and decompress file before saving to disk

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-compression, compression

In my application i have one web service which getting one file from FormData(client side) and i want to compress that file before saving to disk(without using extra folder).

i read a lot of answers from here but i got confused, which method i will use in code behind to achieve better compression.and also i want to decompress that file on the time of access.

Currently in code behind i am using bellow code to save the file directly.

```
var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
// Get the complete file path
var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Download/"), httpPostedFile.FileName);
// Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
```

Comment: You could just enable NTFS compression on the parent folder and then do nothing, compression and de-compression is handled automatically. But if the uploaded files are images, either JPEG, GIF or PNG compressing them wont be very effective as they are already compressed.

Comment: I will upload only images so you are saying i want to manually enable the compression in the solution folder or by code wise.

Comment: I enabled the compression by selecting the properties of that folder but when i tried to upload an image having size (5.7MB)it taking the same size in that folder after uploading,

Comment: Look at the General Properties of the file, you can see `Size on disk` which can be much smaller than `Size` but for most images or small files it may also be bigger than `Size`. It's because images are already compress and compressing them again just adds overhead. Don't bother compressing images, you wont gain any space on your hard drive.

Comment: so images we don't need to compress..

Comment: Correct. Unless you are dealing with old formats like `BMP` that don't have built-in compression.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: the clarity of the images are not important for me,can you tell how to compress the images in c# because I need that in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by different ways,

one of the best way is convert all images into jpeg,because it will give better clarity with less size,in this we don't need to change any height or width of the particular image

method 1 : convert all images into jpeg(no additional compression needed)

```
  private static void VaryQualityLevel(Image imgToResize,string imageName)
      {
        // Get a bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(imgToResize);
        ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
        // for the Quality parameter category.
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

        // Create an EncoderParameters object.
        // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter
        // objects. In this case, there is only one
        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder,
            50L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

        var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Download/"), imageName+".jpeg");
        bmp1.Save(fileSavePath, jgpEncoder,
            myEncoderParameters);

        //myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
        //myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        //fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Download/"), "TestPhotoQuality100.jpeg");
        //bmp1.Save(fileSavePath, jgpEncoder,
        //    myEncoderParameters);

        // Save the bitmap as a JPG file with 75 quality level compression.
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 75L);
        //myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        //fileSavePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Download/"), "TestPhotoQuality75.jpeg");
        //bmp1.Save(fileSavePath, jgpEncoder,
        //    myEncoderParameters);

    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
        }
```

method 2: by changing the height and width of the image(without jpeg conversion)

CommonConstant.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EmptyDemo.compression
{
#region[Directive]
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
#endregion[Directive]

/// <summary>
/// This class is used to get the constants
/// </summary>
public class CommonConstant
{
    public const string JPEG = ".jpeg";
    public const string PNG = ".png";
    public const string JPG = ".jpg";
    public const string BTM = ".btm";
}
}
```

ImageCompress.CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EmptyDemo.compression
{
#region[Directive]
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
#endregion[Directive]

/// <summary>
/// This class is used to compress the image to
/// provided size
/// </summary>
public class ImageCompress
{
    #region[PrivateData]
    private static volatile ImageCompress imageCompress;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Image img;
    #endregion[Privatedata]

    #region[Constructor]
    /// <summary>
    /// It is used to restrict to create the instance of the      ImageCompress
    /// </summary>
    private ImageCompress()
    {
    }
    #endregion[Constructor]

    #region[Poperties]
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets ImageCompress object
    /// </summary>
    public static ImageCompress GetImageCompressObject
    {
        get
        {
            if (imageCompress == null)
            {
                imageCompress = new ImageCompress();
            }
            return imageCompress;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Width
    /// </summary>
    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Width
    /// </summary>
    public int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { width = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Image
    /// </summary>
    public Bitmap GetImage
    {
        get { return bitmap; }
        set { bitmap = value; }
    }
    #endregion[Poperties]

    #region[PublicFunction]
    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to save the image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public void Save(string fileName, string path)
    {
        if (ISValidFileType(fileName))
        {
            string pathaname = path + @"\" + fileName;
            save(pathaname, 60);
        }
    }
    #endregion[PublicFunction]

    #region[PrivateData]
    /// <summary>
    /// This function is use to compress the image to
    /// predefine size
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>return bitmap in compress size</returns>
    private Image CompressImage()
    {
        if (GetImage != null)
        {
            Width = (Width == 0) ? GetImage.Width : Width;
            Height = (Height == 0) ? GetImage.Height : Height;
            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            newBitmap = bitmap;
            newBitmap.SetResolution(80, 80);
            return newBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(Width, Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Please provide bitmap");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to check the file Type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">String data type:contain the file name</param>
    /// <returns>true or false on the file extention</returns>
    private bool ISValidFileType(string fileName)
    {
        bool isValidExt = false;
        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        switch (fileExt.ToLower())
        {
            case CommonConstant.JPEG:
            case CommonConstant.BTM:
            case CommonConstant.JPG:
            case CommonConstant.PNG:
                isValidExt = true;
                break;
        }
        return isValidExt;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to get the imageCode info
    /// on the basis of mimeType
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mimeType">string data type</param>
    /// <returns>ImageCodecInfo data type</returns>
    private ImageCodecInfo GetImageCoeInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codes = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (int i = 0; i < codes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (codes[i].MimeType == mimeType)
            {
                return codes[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// this function is used to save the image into a
    /// given path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">string data type</param>
    /// <param name="quality">int data type</param>
    private void save(string path, int quality)
    {
        img = CompressImage();
        ////Setting the quality of the picture
        EncoderParameter qualityParam =
            new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
        ////Seting the format to save
        ImageCodecInfo imageCodec = GetImageCoeInfo("image/jpeg");
        ////Used to contain the poarameters of the quality
        EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        parameters.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        ////Used to save the image to a  given path
        img.Save(path, imageCodec, parameters);
    }
    #endregion[PrivateData]
}
}
```

Here I am uploading image with the help of jquery and web service and i am passing the file as formdata

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void UploadFile()
     {
         if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
         {
             // Get the uploaded image from the Files collection
             var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedImage"];
             if (httpPostedFile != null)
             {
                 ImageCompress imgCompress = ImageCompress.GetImageCompressObject;
                 imgCompress.GetImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(httpPostedFile.InputStream);
                 imgCompress.Height = 260;
                 imgCompress.Width = 358;
                 //imgCompress.Save(httpPostedFile.FileName, @"C:\Documents and Settings\Rasmi\My Documents\Visual Studio2008\WebSites\compressImageFile\Logo");
                 imgCompress.Save(httpPostedFile.FileName, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Download/"));

             }
         }
     }
```